How to integrate a flutter module into an Android app with AGP 8+
I have an existing Android app with a flutter submodule that builds with Android Gradle Plugin 7.4.2. In order to continue to upgrade its Android libraries (and generally keep it up to date), I need to migrate to AGP 8.4. I am getting errors from my flutter module when running gradle sync with no obvious way to resolve them.
Since the build structure for my app is complex, I created a new simple Android app in Android Studio, and then a new Flutter module, and followed the flutter instructions to integrate the module. When I sync the new project, I get the appended failure. This is different from the error I get in my full project, but if anyone has advice for the cause of this, or has successfully built a flutter module integrated into an AGP 8.x project, that would help.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


Where:
Script '/Users/jhedwards/Development/samples/flutter_module/.android/include_flutter.groovy' line: 4

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.



Could not find method include() for arguments [:flutter] on build of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.


Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating script.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptTarget.addConfiguration(DefaultScriptTarget.java:74)
...
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method include() for arguments [:flutter] on build of type org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle.
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMissingMethodExecutionFailed.(AbstractDynamicObject.java:190)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.methodMissingException(AbstractDynamicObject.java:184)
at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.invokeMethod(AbstractDynamicObject.java:167)
at org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at include_flutter_cyaszvnizwbba934etin1a2h5.run(/Users/jhedwards/Development/samples/flutter_module/.android/include_flutter.groovy:4)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
... 194 more

